# How does $ht^{h-1}(1-t)^{n-h}+t^h (n-h)(1-t)^{n-h-1}(-1)$ become $t^{h-1}(1-t)^{n-h-1}\left[h(1-t)-(n-h)t\right]$?

Tags: binomial-distribution, maximum-likelihood

I'm not sure how to get from the first line to the simplified second line. Equations are from Charles Elkan's notes here:
http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~elkan/250Bwinter2012/logreg.pdf

> $$
> \begin{split}
> \frac{d}{d\theta} \theta^h (1-\theta)^{n-h} &=
> h \theta^{h-1} (1-\theta)^{n-h} + \theta^h (n-h)(1- \theta)^{n-h-1}(-1)\\
> &= \theta^{h-1} (1-\theta)^{n-h-1} \left[ h(1-\theta)- (n-h)\theta \right] 
> \end{split}
> $$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I suggest that you post here the part of the text that you want to ask questions about,

Comment: By extracting common factors

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $(1-\theta)^{n-h} = (1-\theta)\cdot(1-\theta)^{n-h-1}$ and $\theta^h = \theta \cdot\theta^{h-1}$. The common factor of the two terms on the right hand side of the first equation is $\theta^{h-1}\cdot(1-\theta)^{n-h-1}$, so he extracts it (as suggested in the comments).